# Can these accounts on Data.SE please be merged?

Tags: support, data-explorer, merge-accounts

Normally getting accounts merged is a straightforward process that can easily be done by a moderator. However, that is definitely not the case over on [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

I have accidentally created two user accounts there and need them merged. Here they are:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/users/4291/george-edison
- https://data.stackexchange.com/users/10614/nathan-osman

Comment: Ahem.  I was wondering about that... why we have *two penguins with glasses* wandering about the SE sites.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Oh, you mean [changing my name](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8820323#8820323)?